# Show keyboard under specified textfields

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have registration form in my app. It has about 7 fields that user is filling.
But some fields are under the keyboard.

Keyboard is hiding last 3 textfields - so i want to move frame only for them.
I think that it is bad idea to move textfields because i should move not only textfields but labels for each of them.
I don't have constraints to bottom of view. All my elements have vertical spacing from top element is this view.

How it can be done?

I thought that it is obvious and easy to solve but found many suggestions (none of them worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a UIView, and put all your controls(textFields and labels) on top of the view. 
Then whenever user tap the textFields that would be hided by keyboard, you set the "contentInset" value of the UIView to a proper value. 
For instance:
self.palletView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-kKeyboardHeight, 0, -kKeyboardHeight, 0);

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding notification observers for events `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` then update your view constraints accordingly. The following example is in Obj-C not Swift, but you get the idea:

In your controller viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

And and implement the following methods in your controller:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (self.presentedViewController) return;

    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue *kbFrame = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [kbFrame CGRectValue];

    CGFloat height = keyboardFrame.size.height;

    // Update constraints here

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}


- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    // Update constraints here

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

This will animate the changes to your constraints in time with the keyboard animation. In the `keyboardWillShow` method, `height` is the height that the keyboard will be when it is finished showing, so you can subtract this from your view height to get the visible area height.

As you have only constraints to the top of your view, you may want to add one to the bottom of your view as well, with a lower priority. Make those constrains IBOutlets and update their constants and/or set active/inactive as appropriate. (Note: don't try to update the priority, bad things will happen).

If you have too many textfields to fit in the viewable area but want to keep them all displayed, you could consider putting them in a UIScrollView or a UITableView and adjusting the constraints of those views accordingly.